# Export and import premade estimator in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a dataset, which is include 35 features and round about 10000 rows. 
In Addition, i use the premade kmeansClustering from tensorflow tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering).

For export, my serving_input_fn() function looks like

```
def serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = {
        'feature1' : tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]),
        'feature2' : tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]),
        ...

    }
    features = {
        key: tf.expand_dims(tensor, -1)
        for key, tensor in feature_placeholders.items()
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, feature_placeholders)

kmeans.export_savedmodel(
        export_dir_base=path_to_export,
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
```

i will get a pb file and two variable files. How can i import this model and predict with data? My import function looks like

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor
from tensorflow.python.util import compat
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saved_model_pb2

GRAPH_PB_PATH = 'path_to_model/saved_model.pb'

with tf.gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
sess = tf.Session(graph=g_in)
```

but crashed with error message "Error parsing message".

Whats wrong? Is the serving_input_fn() correct?